# Legendre Differential equation

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider 
$$
P_n(x)=\frac{1}{2^n\,n!}\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d}x^n} \left[ (x^2 -1)^n \right]
$$ 
and the Legendre Differential equation 
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left( (1-x^2) \frac{du}{dx}\right) + n(n+1) u = 0.
$$ Why is $P_n$ a solution of this equation? First I used the product rule to calculate 
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left( (1-x^2) \frac{du}{dx}\right),
$$ 
then I used the Binomial theorem  but the calculation is awkward. I have no idea how the calculate effective.. Could you help me? I'm stuck. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, the trick is to first prove the recursive description of $P_n$:

$P_0=1, P_1=x, (n+1)P_{n+1} = (2n+1)x P_n - n P_{n-1}$

Then it should be an easy induction to prove that $P_n$ satisfies the $n$-th ODE.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=(x^2-1)^n$.  We note that

$$f'_n(x)=2nx(x^2-1)^{n-1}$$

and

$$f''_n(x)=2n(x^2-1)^{n-1}+4n(n-1)x^2(x^2-1)^{n-2}$$

Thus, we see that $f_n$ satisfies the ODE

$$(x^2-1)f_n''(x)-2(n-1)xf_n'(x)-2nf_n(x)=0 \tag1$$

Differentiating $(1)$ $n$ times and using the [Leibnitz Identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizIdentity.html) for differentiating a product reveals that

$$(1-x^2)f_n^{(n+2)}(x)-2xf_n^{(n+1)}(x)+n(n+1)f_n^{(n)}(x)=0 \tag2$$

which is Legendre's Equation for $f^{(n)}(x)$. Obviously, the solutions to $(2)$ are the $n'th$ order derivatives

$$\frac{d^{(n)}}{dx^{(n)}}\left(x^2-1\right)^n$$

and we are done!